# Lots of system errors when trying to make tkinter script into app

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2app

I used tkinter to create a GUI for some scripts in python. I would like to turn my scripts into a single app file, but I have run into multiple problems. I am new to .app development, and would appreciate any help!

I followed the steps in the [py2app tutorial](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/py2app/latest/py2app.pdf) and successfully created a setup.py file. But when I try to develop in alias mode by running the command `python setup.py py2app -A`, I get a error.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/sbin/authserver'

I then tried to execute the command `sudo python setup.py py2app -A` and received a

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/.Spotlight-V100'.

Some of the libraries I am using include numpy, scipy, pandas, and nitime.

On a side note, I tried using pyinstaller, but also ran into problems there as well. The .exec file works (opens and runs with clicked) but the .app file does not work (does not open when clicked).

My setup.py file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

DATA_FILES = [<I have files listed here that I removed for this post>]
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=['MyApplication.py'],
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I am out of ideas on what to use and can't find any more answers when Googling. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: PyInstaller with `--onefile  --noconsole` literally calls py2app, so I'm pretty sure it won't work either way. As a Mac user as well, I have faced similar issues with GUI python apps. The inconvenient solution is to go into your pyinstaller/py2app .app "file", enter its package contents, go to Contents/MacOS, and execute the file inside.